# ListView Column Alignment

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 and VS2017, and after importing my project I've noticied that my ListView column headers aren't aliging up properly with the rows below.

I've created a blank new WinForm project in VS and got the same result, in the designer as well as the compiled program.

As my program pretty much centres around this it just doesn't look right, anyone seen this or know how to fix it?

It was working fine on Win7/VS2015, so not sure what's changed?

[image]

Comment: It is a Win10 bug.  They will probably fix it in the next update.